# Firebase Firestore huge amount of reading document concern

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**EDIT:** Basically do you get charge for the documents you query. The answers is no, if you query 100K documents but only get back 10 you only get charge for the 10 documents you get form your query.

Hi so I have been using firebase firestore and it's been great. However, I have some questions about it. Currently, I'm working on an app where users can place orders and by default, the 'isActive' property is true so that the admin can see the orders. When the order is completed the property turns false and doesn't show up. However, eventually, I will accumulate thousands of orders and my question is will I get charged for the documents that I read that is true or it will counts as reading all thousands of documents even though I don't use it.

Comment: [FireBase Charges](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?gclid=CjwKCAiA4o79BRBvEiwAjteoYHK_6UNvO7itEwIfkEIQ4y7VYgBrxCULHNOJ4G0wZYuz-P3k3b5P2hoCCIgQAvD_BwE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simple: if your document is read from/on the server, you will be charged for a document read.

If your clients are not requesting documents with `isActive` is false, they won't generate document read charges for those documents. I your admin *is* reading those documents, *they* will generate read charges for those documents.

Comment: so if i query FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('orders').where({'isActive': true).snapshots I will only get charge for the active docs? No cost for quering all the doc

Comment: That is correct: the query only retrieves the active orders, so that's the most you'll be charged for by this query.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You will most definitely be charged for stored data regardless of if you access it your not. If you do decide to access it you'll be charged for that as well. Fortunately you have 20K free reads a day and then you pay after that.

While I think that answers your question. If your app reads in 20,000 documents in one action (open a page and then it loads in everything) that's not going to scale well for you and that's a lot of data. Which means your client devices will have to process 20K documents which is not ideal.

I'd advise using [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) and then do [pagination or infinite scrolling.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poqTHxtDXwU&t=3s)